# How to show/hide banner, based on it's from_date and end_date in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to work on an index page, and to implement minor modifications to the said page. Currently I do have a banner management section within the admin panel where I'm able to upload an image along with a title. Thus, my index page will show all entered banners as a slide show.

However, I've been trying to make it abit more organized. For that I edited the database and added fields such as banner_id, banner name, Fromdate, EndDate and bannerimage. However instead of showing the entire banner content, I want to show banner image based on the date and time which I added into the database.

is there any way to sort this filtering method? I'm trying to learn and improvise on my own, but then again due to the fact that I'm still a beginner and I do know the logical application I'm failing to implement it code wise.

----This is the current code that I have to handle the slide sow---

```
$image_dir = "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/images/img"; // directory on server
$image_relative_path = 'images/img'; // path to images relative to script
$file_types = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
$image_time = '10000'; // seconds each image will display (4000 = 4 seconds)
$image_rotation ='';

if ($handle = opendir($image_dir)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $ext_bits = explode(".", $file); // finds file extensions
            foreach ($ext_bits as $key => $value) {
                if (in_array($value, $file_types)) { 
                    $image_rotation .= '<div data-p="170.00"><img data-u="image" src="'.$image_relative_path.'/' . $file . '"/></div>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

?>

```
<div class="container">
<div id="jssor_1" style="position:relative;margin:0 auto;top:0px;left:0px;width:1300px;height:500px;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;">
    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div data-u="loading" class="jssorl-009-spin" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);">
        <img style="margin-top:-19px;position:relative;top:50%;width:38px;height:38px;" src="images/spin.svg" />
    </div>
    <div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:1300px;height:500px;overflow:hidden;">
        <?php echo $image_rotation; ?>
    </div>
```

----The above code works fine, but it doesn't give me the privilege to show/hide banner based on the dates entered into the database.---

So, Currently I am uploading each banner as
banner name, banner image, Date & time to start showing banner, end date and end time for banner. (However, I'm using a datepicker that accepts the date and time within a single package.

So, let's say I upload 10 banner, I don't want it to be shown on the index page right away, I want it to be displayed within the dates as per the database

Comment: You have to show us the code, along with the error you're having.

Comment: You can either do it in the SQL or in PHP. I'd recommend to do it via SQL. Good luck!

Comment: sounds like you want a SQL query which will return you some data with a WHERE clause to restrict it by the date and time. You say "based on" the date and time, but that's not a specific enough criteria we can use to actually show you a query...you'd have to say exactly what the input data and expected output would be. Probably easier if you were to show us any code you've tried already, and explain what goes wrong.

Comment: You will always get a better response from this community if you show us the code and any useful example data that may go with the code

Comment: have you actually tried to write a query yet?

Comment: you should avoid inline CSS - it's a bad practice that can lead to unexpected DOM behaviour (e.g. CSS specification) - it's also harder to maintain

Comment: Well I tried a  couple different approach but it didn't work out as expected.

Comment: Show what you tried and what "didn't work out as expected"

Comment: @TreyBake Will keep that in mind, and thanks you for the tip/advice :)  . The method I tried was to call the date, and I tried to separate day, month and time individually into a variable and tried to cross check it with current date in a similar fashion but I assume that wasn't the actual way to implement it. Thus I had to delete it.   Something like $day=date('d', strtotime($row['date']));
        $month=date('m', strtotime($row['date']));
        if($day==date('d')&& $month==date('m')) it's not the full code but it's how I tried to filter date.

Comment: you can compare datetime and find out if it's before/after a range using `<=` (less than or equal to) and `>=` (greater than or equal to) and use dates that way :)

Comment: Oh ya I thought about it but I haven't done many PHP coding myself, I've only re-used and edited on existing code and learned on my own. So I'm unsure on how to implement it. #stressed :(

Answer (score 0):

As this is tagged with `PHP` I'll provide a PHP answer.

With PHP you can compare DateTime by using a variety of [comparison operators](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

For your case, it's best suited to use `<=` (less than or equal to) and `>=` (greater than or equal to).

Your logic will essentially be:

if date is greater than or equal to DateA and is less than or equal to DateB - show banner.

```
<?php
    $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $dateA = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('13 Nov 2018'));
    $dateB = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('21 Dec 2018'));

    echo $today. '<br />';
    echo $dateA. '<br />';
    echo $dateB. '<br />';

    if ($today >= $dateA && $today <= $dateB) {
        echo 'show banner';
    }
```

Here we make use of PHPs in-built functions [date](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to declare today, DateA (the start of the range) and DateB (the end of the range). I used a range I know would display show banner just for examples sake.

Note: This isn't a copy-paste solution, this just shows you an answer to your problem for you to edit/tweak to suit your code :)